# How to write a script to rename the files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have files 
`263_V01_C07_R000_THx_BH_4096H.dat,263_V01_C07_R000_THY_BH_4096H.dat`
and so on 
I would like to change all R000 into R011.I have tried like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.dat; do
  if [[ "$file" =~ _THx_ ]]; then
mv $file $file2
  fi
done
```

But how to define file2?

Comment: @anubhva Yes,It should be mv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute characters in a variable like this

```
file2=${file/R000/R011}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename`:

```
rename R000 R011 *
```

It looks like there are different versions floating around; an older, which is part of the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) project using the syntax above, and a newer by Larry Wall, using a Perl expression for the renaming:

```
rename 's/R000/R011/' *
```

Check the man page of your `rename` to see which one you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rename

```
rename 's/R000/R011/' *.dat
```